# Problem in Request.Cookies["refreshToken"] in a gRPC service

Tags: c#, cookies, grpc, refresh-token

I'm trying get a Refresh Token via Request but it gives me a error CS0117 saying that Request don't exist. I don't know if is because I use gRPC services or other thing because I use this in a Web Api and it work perfect.

This is the lines of code and the libraries that I use

Libraries

```
using Grpc.Core;
using Grpc_Server_1.Context.UserDAL;
using Grpc_Server_1.Entities;
using Grpc_Server_1.Entities.Interfaces;
using Grpc_Server_1.Protos;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
```

Line of code that gives me error

```
 //This is just to get the refresh token of a user, check if is empty or not
 if (userInDb.RefreshToken.IsNullOrEmpty() == false){
    
    //This is my error, gives me error in Request, I also try the line below but it don't 
    //work
 
     var a = Request.Cookies["refreshToken"]; 
     //var a = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];

     //check if user refresh token equals refresh token from a cookie           
     if (!userInDb.RefreshToken.Equals(a))
     { //throw a Exception error
     }
 }
```

This is the problem (how to get the Request/HttpRequest), also I'm using .Net 6 for my project, so the problem can be in some part of the program.cs or also in the appSettings or even also in some NuGet package. Any answer is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Edit / Half-Answer :

For not getting the error I use HttpContext as a variable, something like this:

```
private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

//...

var a = _httpContext.Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];
```

Now the problem is, "Is this ok?" because I don't know if this implementation is the best way to fix the error and if a gRPC service recognize this

Anyways I will put this answer if anyone will have future problems